# url name accessing another view

Tags: django

I have two path in urls.py file. When I hit a url,instead of picking intended url it is picking another one why?
Can anyone please help me.

This is my urls.py file:

```
 from . import views
 from django.urls import path

 app_name = 'olx'

 path('<slug:category_slug>/',views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),

 path('myPost/', views.myPost, name='my_all_post'),
```

In my html file I am using anchor tag like this:

```
 <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url "olx:my_all_post" %}">My Post
            </a>
          </li>
```

I tried replacing double inverted commas with single inverted commas like this:

```
 href="{% url 'olx:my_all_post' %}"
```

but still it is picking another path:

```
 <slug:category_slug>/
```

but if I remove the below path from my urls.py file then it is picking the correct one.

```
 path('<slug:category_slug>/',views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
```

Comment: Have you tried swapping the urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL pattern,

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/',views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
```

will match any url such as,

```
/something/
```

or

```
/something-else/
```

or

```
/myPost/
```

what you could do is change that pattern to something like,

```
path('categories/<slug:category_slug>/',views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the ordering of your URL pattern definitions.

`'myPost'` is a valid slug, so `'<slug:category_slug>/'` will match it.

Change your order like so:

```
path('myPost/', views.myPost, name='my_all_post'),
path('<slug:category_slug>/',views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
```